# How can I open a Google Chrome application shortcut on Windows 8 start up?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-8

Hi I have created a Google Chrome Application Short cut for a URL (in Windows 8) as detailed in [Google Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95710?hl=en-GB) under the heading *Create shortcuts for other apps*. I've stored the shortcut on the desktop.

I need a way of making one specific application shortcut open when Windows 8 starts up, and I'm wondering if anyone knows a way of doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy the shortcut to AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup.

Comment: Thank you!! That's the one!